# How to turn the internal sound note into the form of function

Tags: fourier-analysis, sound

I want to make a brief `Fourier` transformation of the sound notes of the same pitch but played by different instruments to see the difference of their Fourier patterns. But I can't find any example of showing `SoundNote` in the function form or any similar operation in the Documentation Center.

So I hope someone could help me on this. Thank you in advance, sincerely.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "showing `SoundNote` in the function form", but if you want a list of audio samples corresponding to a `SoundNote[]`, use `AudioData[]`:

```
dat = AudioData[SoundNote["C", 1, "Marimba"]];
```

Then you can e.g. plot the logarithmic spectrum per channel:

```
ListLinePlot[Log10[Abs[Fourier[#]]^2] & /@ dat]
```

[image: logarithmic spectrum of 1s of middle C, marimba-style]

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I mean, sir. I'm just a greenhorn, and I'm trying to writer a paper on music and Fourier transformation. Thank you very much!~~